# How to add parent object to child in a one-to-may relationship in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have two models in ember.js with a one-to-may relationship. Now I want to create a new child object and need to assign an associated parent object. I can't figure out how to do this. My models are defined with the following code:

model of parent-object

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    children: DS.hasMany('child')
});
```

model of child-object

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    parent: DS.belongsTo('parent')
});
```

In the `model()`-method of the route create a child object.

```
var child = this.store.createRecord('child');
```

and then query for the parent-object.

```
var parent = this.findRecord('parent', 2);
```

Then I tried to bind them together but anythig I tried failed. For example:

```
parent.get('child').addObject(child) // or
parent.get('child').pushObject(child) // or
child.set('parent', parent)
```

These things result in `parent` not having anything in `child` and `child` not having anything in `parent`. I also did some attempts with async promise resolving but with no success. It would be great if someone could post an example how to manage this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this works as you expect. But you have a few minor errors:

- Sometimes you use `child` and sometimes `child-object`. Same goes for `parent`.
- `findRecord` returns a `PromiseObject`. You probably want to wait for the promise to resolve.
- Its not `addObject`.

Also you can do it from both sides. Either set the parent:

```
this.store.findRecord('parent-object', 2).then(parent => {
  const child = this.store.createRecord('child-object');
  child.set('parent', parent);
});
```

Or you add the child to the children:

```
this.store.findRecord('parent-object', 2).then(parent => {
  const child = this.store.createRecord('child-object');
  parent.get('children').pushObject(child);
});
```

Maybe check out [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/26158f912194f24d198ff5d3a7309224?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

Comment: Triple A! That's exactly what I was searching for. I thought I had tried this one, too, but obviously not. Maybe it's worth to note that one has to `return` the whole expression as well as the `child` (the `parent` in the second example) to assign the model to the controller.